# GeoPandas drops .prj file

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas, python-3

I'm trying to create a df through a GeoJSON url, merge it with a df created out of a SQL query, and create a shapefile/GeoJSON from the output. The output has everything put the .prj file (in the instance of a shapefile output). I've tried to set the CRS later in the code but it doesn't stay. I've discovered at some point in the merge, it drops the CRS.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

url = 'http is private just for this example.geojson'
df = gpd.read_file(url)
df = df.rename(columns={'MAINADDRESS': 'Address'})

cnxn = pyodbc.connect( xxxx)

sql = sql query
sql1 = 2nd sql query

df1 = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
df1a = pd.read_sql(sql1, cnxn)

df4b = pd.merge(df1a, df1, on='strap')
df4c = df.merge(df4b, on='Address', how='left')
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df4c, geometry='geometry')
print(gdf.crs)
gdf.to_file('rentals.shp')
gdf.to_file('rentals.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

The print(gdf.crs) shows 'None'.

Comment: I guess that you must set it with the code. Dropping the original CRS may make sense because your SQL can well be `select ST_Tranform(geometry,xxxx)`.